# using affectiva sdk in telegram messenger in android

Tags: android, android-studio, telegram, affdex-sdk

I have a research base project which uses `affectiva` SDK emotion detection tool while Android users are working with Telegram messenger. I'm using latest telegram messenger version provided by this [github page](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram). Therefore, I need to add Affectiva libraries. According to affectiva developer portal, I tried to add the SDK, by declaring a dependency on the SDK in build.gradle file. Thus, the task is to merge these 2 applications into one.
After syncing gradle, when I try to build project several errors appear. I think the main error is about merging manifests.

Some possible solution I have tried:

Updating gradle to latest version

Set minsdkVersion and targetsdkVersion to 16 and 24, respectively

Add the following code to defualtconfig block in build.gradle file

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

add following code to dependencies instead what instruction said.

```
compile ('com.affectiva.android:affdexsdk:3.1.2')
            {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
            }
```

Dear affectiva support team, please check this problem and I will glad to hear from your team and I can provide additional information.
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @AndyDennie after a while, finally, I found the problem.
I should follow your instructions and apply them in manifest and debug_manifest.
BTW, I appreciate you for your attention.

Comment: @Payam I'm curious about how you are using the emotion SDK in telegram .. Can u share more information about what you are doing ..

Comment: @AndyDennie I'm working on my master thesis which aims to detect user's mood. In more detail, we used facial cues including expressions and emotions while users are interacting with Telegram messenger. After that, we applied machine learning methods to determine user's current mood. BTW, my results are written as an academic paper which will be published in the near future. I will be more than happy if you kindly review it as well as evaluate our findings and results.